# List menu hover & active text color can't be changed despite background color changing

Tags: html, css

I keep trying to change the hover/active text color of my drop down menu to    #8AE4E6. However, for some reason it isn't work. I tried adding color:#8AE4E6 under the background-color line but it doesn't seem to change. Also, for some reason my links are purple and orange once active. I don't see in my code every setting these colors. Is this the default? My color for body is white.

Thanks!

Here's the HTML and CSS

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css"/>

<title>SITETEST</title>



</head>

<body>
<div id="bottom"></div>
<div id="surround"></div>

<p id="bottomtext">A  -  W O R K  - I N  -  P R O G R E S S</p>
<p id="title">YLDNA'S SITE</p>
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap" >
<ul>
  <li class="hvr-fade"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li class="hvr-fade" ><a href="#">INTRODUCTION</a></li>
  <li class="hvr-fade"><a href="#">COMMITTEES</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="hvr-fade"><a href="#">Security Council</a></li>
      <li class="hvr-fade"><a href="#">CDIS</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="hvr-fade"><a href="#">EXECUTIVES</li>
 <li class="hvr-fade"><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
   <li class="hvr-fade"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>



 html{

     min-height:100%;

     background-size:cover;
     background-attachment: fixed;


 body {
    font-family: 'telegrafico'; 
     font-size: 1.1em;
     text-align: center;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline;
 max-width: 100%;
 background-color:#8AE4E6;
 background-size:cover;
 color:white;
}



 #primary_nav_wrap
 {
    margin-top:15px;

 }

 #primary_nav_wrap ul
 {
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    top:100%;
    left:27.5%;
     padding:0;
     max-width:50%;
     min-width:50%;
     max-height:500px;
     min-height:21%;
     color:white;


 }

 #primary_nav_wrap ul a
 {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:12px;
     line-height:32px;
     padding:0 15px;
     font-family: 'open sans'; 
     font-size: 0.9em;
     font-weight:200;
      text-align:center;


 }

 #primary_nav_wrap ul li
 {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
 }

 #primary_nav_wrap ul ul
 {
     display:none;
     position:absolute;
     top:106%;
     left:-25%;
     padding:0px;
     text-align:left;

 }

 #primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
 {
    float:left;
     width:190px;   



 }

 #primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
 {
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 0px;

 }

 #primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
 {
    top:0;
    left:100%
 }

 #primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
 {
    display:block;

 }



 .hvr-fade {
   display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: #8AE4E6;


   vertical-align: middle;
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   transform: translateZ(0);
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
   transition-duration: 0.3s;
   -webkit-transition-property: color, background-color;
   transition-property: color, background-color;
   color: #8AE4E6;

 }

 .hvr-fade:hover, .hvr-fade:focus, .hvr-fade:active {
  background-color:white;
  color:#8AE4E6;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The links colors are not changing because you are not targeting the links.
Change your code to this -

```
/* target anchors*/

 .hvr-fade a:hover, .hvr-fade a:focus, .hvr-fade a:active {
  background-color:white;
  color:#8AE4E6;
 }
/* target anchors*/
```

Also close the style for `html{}`

```
html{

     min-height:100%;

     background-size:cover;
     background-attachment: fixed;
    } /* missing curly bracket in your question*/
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for helping me! It did work for the hover portion. However, prior to hovering, the text is still purple (for some reason). I can't, for the life of me, figure out how that happened and how to change it. I tried changing #primary_nav_wrap ul a to add color:white. However, that overlaps with the hover and makes it white. Do you know what I'm overlooking?

Comment: Same answer can be used. That is- target the `anchors` . In this case `nav li a{color:green}`